# Stripe.js forwards user to url, but paymentIntent has the status "requires_payment_method"

Tags: reactjs, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm setting up a stripe workflow using a stripe.js PaymentElement. The payment is able to clear, and redirect the user to the url given to stripe. However, when the backend queries the status of the paymentIntent, the status is "requires_payment_method" for several seconds.

The frontend is react, the backend is ruby on rails.

This is how the intent is created:

```
intent =
  Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
    {
      amount: my_amount,
      currency: "usd",
      automatic_payment_methods: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      metadata: {
        #...
      },
    },
  )
render json: { client_secret: intent.client_secret, pi_id: intent.id }
```

This is the handler that sends the payment:

```
const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();

const handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
  if (!stripe || !elements) return;

  const paymentElement = elements.getElement('payment');
  if (!paymentElement) return;

  await stripe
    .confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: my_url,
      },
    });
};
```

This is how the intent is queried on the controller for `my_url`:

```
payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve({ id: params[:pi_id] })
raise "Payment Error" unless payment_intent.status == "succeeded"
```

I would expect that after the user is forwarded to the new page, the payment intent would be in "succeeded" status. However, it is frequently in "requires_payment_method" status. Requerying the intent from IRB, the intent eventually resolves to "succeeded" after several seconds. Do I need to poll this every time?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few seconds for the payment confirmation to complete and the payment to be successful. You *can* poll the Payment Intent, but instead what you *should* do is set up a webhook listener and handle `payment_intent.succeeded` events to determine when the payment has transitioned to `succeeded`.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-post-payment